# Stochastic integration and use of ito's lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

**Note to the moderators: This question has been solved, and is indeed a valid question. Please post a comment explaning what needs to be elaborated on. Thank you very much! - random0620**

**Proposition 6.7** Let $X, Y \in \mathcal{P}, M \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathrm{c}}^2$ and $S \leq T$ be stopping times. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{E}\left[\left((X \cdot M)_{T \wedge t}-(X \cdot M)_{S \wedge t}\right)\left((Y \cdot M)_{T \wedge t}-(Y \cdot M)_{S \wedge t}\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_S\right]= 
 \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{S \wedge t}^{T \wedge t} X_u Y_u \mathrm{~d}\langle M\rangle_u \mid \mathcal{F}_S\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

I am wondering how to solve this stochastic calculus question. In the question, $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of pre-visible processes. $\mathcal{M}_c^2$ is the set of square integrable martingales.

---

**My attempt:** I used the following formula :

$$(X \cdot M)_{min(T,t)} - (X \cdot M)_{min(S,t)} = \int_{min(S,t)}^{min(T,t)} X_s \, dM_s$$

$$ \mathbb{E}\left(\left[(X \cdot M)_{min(T,t)} - (X \cdot M)_{min(S,t)}\right]\left[(Y \cdot M)_{T^t} - (Y \cdot M)_{S^t}\right]\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{min(S,t)}^{min(T,t)} X_s \, dM_s \times \int_{min(S,t)}^{min(T,t)} Y_s \, dM_s\right]$$

Is there some way I can use the Ito formula to proceed in this question?

Comment: What about stochastic integration by parts? It’s a corollary of Ito’s formula.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @random_0620 My guess is the question could still be closed because of a picture instead of a MathJax formatted text.

Comment: @Aig Hmm this might be true. I fixed it.

Comment: Still not sure why this is not approved. Would someone please be able to provide me clarity on this?

Answer (score 0):

By stochastic integration by parts, which is a simple corollary of Ito's formula,

$$
X_t Y_t-X_0 Y_0=\int_0^t X_S d Y_s+\int_0^t Y_S d X_S+\int_0^t d X d Y
$$

we have

$$\left((X \cdot M)_{T \wedge t}-(X \cdot M)_{S \wedge t}\right)\left((Y \cdot M)_{T \wedge t}-(Y \cdot M)_{S \wedge t}\right) \\=(X\cdot M)_{T\land t}(Y\cdot M)_{T\land t} -(X\cdot M)_{S\land t}(Y\cdot M)_{S\land t}\\
 = \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}X_sd(Y\cdot M)_{s} + \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}Y_sd(X\cdot M)_{s} + \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}d(X\cdot M)d(Y\cdot M) \\
$$

Now we have that

$$d(X\cdot M)d(Y\cdot M)= (XdM)(YdM) = XYdMdM = XYd\langle M\rangle.$$

Thus,
$$ = \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}X_sd(Y\cdot M)_{s} + \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}Y_sd(X\cdot M)_{s} + \int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}X_sY_sd\langle M\rangle_s. \\$$

But after taking expectation, and applying Optional stopping which leaves only the variation term, we are left with

$$\mathbb{E}\left[(X\cdot M)|_{T\land t}(Y\cdot M)|_{T\land t} -(X\cdot M)|_{S\land t}(Y\cdot M)|_{S\land t}|\mathcal{F}_S\right]= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{S\land t}^{T\land t}X_sY_sd\langle M \rangle_s|\mathcal{F}_S\right]$$